# How to query EWS for a Calendar Message Body

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm looking for a little more details than what was given in this answer: [Exchange EWS not returning message body for calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904649/exchange-ews-not-returning-message-body-for-calendar)

Specifically I'm not sure how to get a calendar message's body in a query.

My XML query is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <m:ItemShape>
                <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
                <t:AdditionalProperties>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Body"/>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Start"/>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:End"/>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Location"/>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Attachments"/>
                </t:AdditionalProperties>
            </m:ItemShape>
            <m:CalendarView EndDate="2016-07-08T00:00:00Z" MaxEntriesReturned="999999" StartDate="2016-07-07T00:00:00Z"/>
            <m:ParentFolderIds>
                <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar"/>
            </m:ParentFolderIds>
        </m:FindItem>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But I seem to be getting an error with:

```
<t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Body"/>
```

## Error Message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="534" MinorBuildNumber="21"/>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <m:FindItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
          <m:MessageText>Property is not valid for this operation.</m:MessageText>
          <m:ResponseCode>ErrorInvalidPropertyForOperation</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
          <m:MessageXml>
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Body"/>
          </m:MessageXml>
        </m:FindItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:FindItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I've looked over the API Here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa494315(v=exchg.150).aspx

And I think I must be missing something simple.  Is there a way using a specific field based query to get a calendar body?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The FindItem operation doesn't return the Body, Attendees and other complex/large properties see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vikas/2007/07/26/ews-why-does-not-finditem-return-all-the-fields-you-expected/ .

So you need to take the ItemId you get from the FindItem Request and then either make a single GetItem Request https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa564509(v=exchg.150).aspx or if you need it for multiple Items batch the GetItem Request together for efficiency.